# LIght bulb to light up

Tags: arduino-uno, led

I'd like to write a JavaScript function that lights up an led light for X milliseconds depending on the response from the JavaScript function.

```
function HowManySeconds() {
   setTimeout(HowManySeconds,5000)
   return 1000
}
```

The JavaScript function will come from a website, so I suppose I would need an Internet enabled device that connects to my router and can 'browse' to my website.

Q: What do I need to buy? A [tessel](https://tessel.io/)? An [Espruino](http://www.espruino.com/)?

Comment: This is an Arduino forum.

Comment: I'm a newbie, so I'm not sure where to start. I don't want to invest a lot of time and money on something only to find out I could have done it easier and cheaper by buying something else or newer.

Comment: Just to clarify: You want a gadget (eg. an Arduino) connected to an Ethernet cable, which queries your website from time to time, and depending on what that website returns, turns on a light (ie. activates an output) for a few milliseconds. Is that it?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to make the scenario as simple as possible. But I'm a web developer, so I can write the JavaScript. But I need a gadget that when plugged in, will automatically interrogate my web page and light up for the number of milliseconds that is returned. I can have the JavaScript running in an infinite loop so that it's constantly polling.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the intel galileo or the intel edison with arduino shield. They can be programmed with a variant of the arduino ide, but it is possible to call also programs from the native linux os. Or you could have a look at the esp826.
At least on the edison it is possible to run node.js, while the esp supports lua.